# Commas and "ands" in excel - conditional merging of cells

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to merge information from up to 12 different cells into a single cell, with commas between the entry from each cell. Further, I would like for the comma between the penultimate and ultimate entry to be replaced with an "and". Of the 12 input cells, only some will have a value in any given instance; therefore, if there are 4 cells with an input and 8 blank cells, I would like the output to be inputcell 1, inputcell 2, inputcell 3 and inputcell 4. Conversely, if there were 6 cells with an input and 6 blank cells, I would like the output to be inputcell 1, inputcell 2, inputcell 3, inputcell 4, inputcell 5 and inputcell 6.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you looked in to `TEXTJOIN()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this vba code,

```
Sub concatWithCommas()
Dim i As Long, str As String, j As Long
str = ""
For j = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To 12
    If Cells(j, i) <> "" Then
        str = str & Cells(j, i) & ","
    End If
Next i
str = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)
Cells(j, 13) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(str, ",", " and ", (Len(str) - Len(Replace(str, ",", ""))))
str = ""
Next j
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, thanks. Apologies for the poor wording of question and lack of example, I'm new to both VBA and stackoverflow. I was wondering if there was a way to apply to above code to a specific range of cells? i.e my inputs are in cells B13:E13,B14:E14,B19:E19.

Comment: @BenMagnin Please mark my answer as correct to make this question resolved

Comment: Have done so - would you know how to apply the above code to specific input cells? i.e B13:E13,B14:E14,B19:E19. I have tried defining a range, but I'm so new to VBA that I hardly know where to begin. Thanks.

Comment: @BenMagnin you have to adjust the i and j loop counters. Simple